# Zend framework 2: How to get custom config from model?

Tags: configuration, model, zend-framework2

In my application, there are custom configs and I want to get them into the model.

I read about one way, but it can not perform:

```
namespace Core\Model;

use Zend\Db\TableGateway\AbstractTableGateway;
use Zend\Db\TableGateway\Feature\FeatureSet;
use Zend\Db\TableGateway\Feature\GlobalAdapterFeature;
use Zend\Db\Sql\Delete,
    Zend\Db\Sql\Insert,
    Zend\Db\Sql\Update,
    Zend\Db\Sql\Select;

use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorAwareInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;

class BaseModel extends AbstractTableGateway implements ServiceLocatorAwareInterface
{

    protected $serviceLocator;

    public function setServiceLocator(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator) {
        $this->serviceLocator = $serviceLocator;
    }

    public function getServiceLocator() {
        return $this->serviceLocator;
    }

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->featureSet = new FeatureSet();
        $this->featureSet->addFeature(new GlobalAdapterFeature());
        $this->initialize();
    }
}
```

In the model I prescribe

```
$config = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('config');
```

or

```
$config = $this->getServiceLocator();
```

but the result = `NULL`

Who can tell what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: what about: $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Configuration');

Comment: How are you creating instances of your BaseModel class? If you're not pulling it from the application's pre-configured service manager, the service locator will not be automatically injected into your object.

Answer (score 2):

You have to create instances of your classes that extend `BaseModel` using the ServiceManager. If you use `new`, then you have to set the ServiceManager yourself.